# In Bootstrap 2.3.2, how can I change the span number of a div when the window size changes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, yii-extensions, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am using YiiStrap, a Yii extension, which currently comes with twitter bootstrap 2.3.2.

I have two elements in one row which are each span6.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vel tristique dolor, ut vehicula mi. Donec nec dui a nisl tincidunt suscipit. Pellentesque venenatis libero ac augue suscipit, vitae tristique arcu posuere.
  </div>

  <div class="span6 visible-desktop">
    <img src="large_photo.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

This works great for the desktop size, but once I shrink the window to the phone size, I would like to remove the second element, using the .visible-desktop class.

Now I am left with only one element that still has a span6 but I would like for it to be at span12. Is there any way I can specify to have it change the remaining element to span12 whenever we're not at the desktop size? I know this is possible in Bootstrap 3, but unfortunately I am stuck with 2.3.2 if I want to use YiiStrap.

Comment: Under 767px, the span6 should expand and act like a span12 automatically, as long as the bootstrap.responsive.css file is included. Do you want it to expand earlier than 767px?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with jQuery, I don't  know the extact sintax but I know you can use the `.toggleClass()` to switch between the span6 - span12 and the `width()`, `=<` to check the width of an element, everything widthin a `if{}` sentense. I'm new on jQuery so I can't tell you more, hope this to be useful

http://api.jquery.com/?s=width

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/